# How to move facebook likes on wordpress from one domain to another

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, wordpress

**Background**

I have a domain say www.foo.com. I host my wordpress blog there.
There are many facebook likes on the posts i have put up.
Now I have redirected www.foo.com to www.boo.com and closed the foo.com domain.(On the server i have simply copied the files from foo.com to boo.com's folder.The database is the same for both.)

**Problem**

The problem i am facing is that the facebook likes are "Gone". How can i retrieve the facebook likes? Are the likes linked to domain name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this.  Even if in your case it is a valid request - think about the meaning of this action.  if it were possible people couild just move likes from pages to other pages, from applications and from websites... users that liked "foo.com" **DIDNT** like "boo.com", the fact that the content is exactly the same is purely coincidence.  The user did not "like" that second URL therefore you can not "move" likes...  
Perhaps if you contact facebook (as a developer) they might be able to assist you - but there is no method that us (non Mark Zuckerberg types) can do.

Comment: You are right, but just wanted to confirm this. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Oh yes, you can, quite easily :) In the like iframe, look at src. You'll see a link to facebook, with a redirect to your website. Put there your old website, and there you go - likes are back.

Comment: The like's are bound to the URL - if you change the URL a different like count for a different URL will appear.  The OP wants to preserve the likes but move to a new domain. **That** simply is not possible...

Answer (score 10):

You **can** do this with a 301 redirect, although its not 100% reliable.

I kept my goggle page rank and facebook page likes when moving between www.foo.co.uk and www.foo.com I completely changed the design and url (although foo was the same). Facebook and google+ and google page rank followed the 301's and attributed it to the new page. Having said that if your original site is closed it may be a problem.